Order in the isomorphism between $l_2 \times l_2$ and $l_2$
I know that $l_2 \times l_2$ is a Hilbert space and so it must be isomorphic to $l_2$, however I'm looking for how exactly does this isomorphism works because the basis of $l_2 \times l_2$ is something of the form $(e_i,e_j)$ where each $e_i$ is an element of a basis of $l_2$, but my problem is that the canonical isomorphism between Hilbert spaces is of the form:
$x \rightarrow (\langle x,e_n \rangle)_{n \in N}$ for a basis $e_i$. However in my case this would lead to something of the form:
$(x,y) \rightarrow (\langle (x,y),(e_i,e_j) \rangle ) = ( \langle x,e_i \rangle + \langle y, e_j \rangle)_{i,j \in N}$, however this isn't explicitelly in the form of the basis of $l_2$ so I'm wondering if you can take an enumeration of $N \times N$ to properly express this in the form of the basis of $l_2$. I'm really looking for something like this because I want to see how the terms move once we take elements from $l_2 \times l_2$ to $l2$. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Is pairing function what you are looking for? (Suppose you fix your question to $\ell_2\otimes\ell_2$ as Robert Israel mentioned in their answer, and update the definition of inner product accordingly)

Yes but my question was if that doesn't break continuity in any form

No, the pairs $(e_i, e_j)$ for $i,j \in \mathbb N$ correspond to a basis of the tensor product $\ell_2 \otimes \ell_2$, not the Cartesian product $\ell_2 \times \ell_2$.  The Cartesian product has a basis consisting of $(e_i, 0)$ and $(0, e_i)$ for $i \in \mathbb N$.  Thus
$(x,y)\in \ell_2 \times \ell_2$ where $x = \sum_i x_i e_i$ and $y = \sum_i y_i e_i$ corresponds to the sequence
$(x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2, x_3, y_3, \ldots) \in \ell_2$.

Ok thanks. But in the case of the tensor product could I do something like this? To enumerate the pairs and then do the correspondence like I said?

Yes, that would work.

And it doesn't break continuity or something right?
